# Gunicorn is throwing Out of Memory

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a `Flask` application which is written on top of `Python`. I am running this application with Gunicorn. At a time I am throwing some requests to `Gunicorn` which are sync in nature. Number of requests are not more then 30 at a time. I have 17 different `Machine Learning models` and for each model I have a Gunicorn process. So in total I have 34 processes if we count Master and Worker as different processes. Overall in the starting it is taking around `22Gb`. But as the application keeps on running, Gunicorn memory keeps on increasing. And after some time it force the `Kernel` to stop other applications like Jetty because of `Out of Memory`.
Can someone tell me how to debug this issue?

Comment: use a profiler, pycharm is supposed to have a good one

Comment: Probable your services create `internal loop`, some resources stay on `cross calling`. More service on same machine need create a `service guardian`, `Threated Socket` always faster than `other wsgi service application`. An example why don't use any ready for use `WSGI` service: All RFU(ready for use) WSGI applications got logging, but which user can handle this ? Basic/simple always is **good**.

Answer (score 0):

That looks to be an expected behavior from gunicorn. The memory consumed by each worker would increase over time. You should try setting the max-requests parameter in your gunicorn settings (say *N*) to indicate the worker to restart after processing *N* number of requests. You can check more at http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html